# Run shell commands in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to execute a program through my Elixir code. What is the method to call a shell command to a given string? Is there anything which isn't platform specific?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Here is how you execute a simple shell command without arguments:

```
System.cmd("whoami", [])
# => {"lukas\n", 0}
```

Checkout the documentation about [`System`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3) for more information.

Answer (score 16):

`System.cmd/3` seems to accept the arguments to the command as a list and is not happy when you try to sneak in arguments in the command name.

For example:

```
System.cmd("ls", ["-al"]) #works, while
System.cmd("ls -al", []) #does not.
```

What in fact happens underneath is `System.cmd/3` calls `:os.find_executable/1` with its first argument, which works just fine for something like `ls` but returns false for `ls -al` for example.

The Erlang call expects a char list instead of a binary, so you need something like the following:

```
"find /tmp -type f -size -200M |xargs rm -f" |> String.to_char_list |> :os.cmd
```

Comment: This behaviour is goof for security; if the string passed to System.cmd comes from an unsafe source, *not* using a shell to parse it closes some attack vectors.

Answer (score 12):

You can have a look in the [Erlang os Module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html). E.g. `cmd(Command) -> string()` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Or `System.cmd/1` from Erlang that works with Elixir strings. :)

Comment: There is another important difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594988/run-shell-commands-in-elixir#comment129789332_73490064

Answer (score 9):

The "devinus/sh" library is another interesting approach to run shell commands.

https://github.com/devinus/sh

Comment: Just FYI, this hasn't been updated in a couple years

Answer (score 5):

I cannot link directly to the relevant documentation but it's [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/) under the `System` module

```
cmd(command) (function) # 
Specs:

cmd(char_list) :: char_list
cmd(binary) :: binary
Execute a system command.

Executes command in a command shell of the target OS, captures the standard output of the command and returns the result as a binary.

If command is a char list, a char list is returned. Returns a binary otherwise.
```

Answer (score 0):

One could also use erlang's `:os` module like so:

```
iex(3)> :os.cmd('time')
'\nreal\t0m0.001s\nuser\t0m0.000s\nsys\t0m0.000s\n'
```

Beware that you'll have to handle erlang binaries when processing the result `:os.cmd('time') |> to_string()` for example

Comment: Also, `:os.cmd` is quite different from `System.cmd` and more dangerous: it passes the string directly to the shell, which will interpret special characters such as `*`. Never call `:os.cmd` with variables provided from the outside. `System.cmd` does not use the shell and is therefore safer.

Answer (score -1):

If I have the following c program in the file `a.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int arc, char** argv)
{

    printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",argv[2]);

    int num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int num2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    return num1*num2;
}
```

and compile the program to the file `a`:

```
~/c_programs$ gcc a.c -o a
```

then I can do:

```
~/c_programs$ ./a 3 5
3
5
```

I can get the return value of main() like this:

```
~/c_programs$ echo $?
15
```

Similarly, in `iex` I can do this:

```
iex(2)> {output, status} = System.cmd("./a", ["3", "5"])
{"3\n5\n", 15}

iex(3)> status
15
```

The second element of the tuple returned by [System.cmd()](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3) is the return value of the main() function.