# Function executed via Erlport stops responding

Tags: python, elixir, linear-programming, pulp

I am writing my thesis application. I need linear programming, but my app is written in Elixir, which is really not the language for such operations. That is why I decided to use Erlport as the Elixir dependency, which is capable of connecting Python code with Elixir. I'm also using Pulp as the python library for the optimization.

Elixir version: 1.10.4,
Erlport version: 0.10.1,
Python version: 3.8.5,
PuLP version: 2.3

I've written such a module for Elixir-Python communication, which leverages the GenServer as the main 'communication hub' between Elixir and Python:

```
defmodule MyApp.PythonHub do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_opts) do
    path = [:code.priv_dir(:feed), "python"]
          |> Path.join() |> to_charlist()

    {:ok, pid} = :python.start([{ :python_path, path }, { :python, 'python3' }])

    {:ok, pid}
  end

  def handle_call({:call_function, module, function_name, arguments}, _sender, pid) do
    result = :python.call(pid, module, function_name, arguments)
    {:reply, result, pid}
  end

  def call_python_function(file_name, function_name, arguments) do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:call_function, file_name, function_name, arguments}, 10_000)
  end

end
```

The GenServer module is calling python file, which contains such a function:

```py
def calculate_meal_4(products_json, diet_json, lower_boundary, upper_boundary, enhance):
  from pulp import LpMinimize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable, value
  import json
  products_dictionary = json.loads(products_json)
  print(products_dictionary)
  diets_dictionary = json.loads(diet_json)
  print(diets_dictionary)

  model = LpProblem(name="diet-minimization", sense=LpMinimize)

  # ... products setup ...

  x = LpVariable("prod_1_100g", lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
  y = LpVariable("prod_2_100g", lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
  z = LpVariable("prod_3_100g", lower_boundary, upper_boundary)
  w = LpVariable("prod_4_100g", lower_boundary, upper_boundary)

  optimization_function = # ... optimization function setup ...

  model += # ... optimization boundary function setup ...

  model += optimization_function

  print(model)

  solved_model = model.solve()

  print(value(model.objective))

  return [value(x), value(y), value(z), value(w)]
```

The call to the GenServer itself looks like that:

```
PythonHub.call_python_function(:diets, python_function, [products_json, meal_statistics_json, @min_portion, @max_portion, @macro_enhancement])
```

where *python_function* is *:calculate_meal_4* and *products_json* and *meal_statistic_json* are jsons containing required data.

While calling *calculate_meal_4* via *python3 diets.py*, which launches the python script above with some example, but real (taken from the app), data everything works fine - I've got the minimized result in almost no time. The problem occurs while calling the python script via Elixir Erlport. Looking at the printed outputs I can tell that it seems working until

```py
solved_model = model.solve()
```

is called. Then the script seems to freeze and GenServer finally reaches the timeout on *GenServer.call* function.

I've tested also the call on a simple python test file:

```py
def pass_var(a):
  print(a)
  return [a, a, a]
```

and it worked fine.

That is why I am really consterned right now and I am looking for any advices. Shamefully I found nothing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it might be that calling an external solver freezes the process.

Given that [you can execute bash scripts using elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261218/5015356), you can easily change the python script to be command line executable (I recommend [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)). Then, you can write the output to a `.json` or `.csv` file and read it back in with Elixir when you're done.

```py
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument('products_json', help='your array of products')
@click.argument('diet_json', help='your dietary wishes')
@click.option('--lower-bound', default=0, help='your minimum number of desired calories')
@click.option('--upper-bound', default=100, help='your maximum number of desired calories')
@click.option('--enhance', default=False, help="whether you'd like to experience our enhanced experience")
def calculate_meal_4(products_json, diet_json, lower_boundary, upper_boundary, enhance):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

which you can then call using `python3 my_file.py <products_json> <diet_json> ...` et cetera.

You can even [validate the JSON and then return the parsed data directly](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/examples/validation/validation.py).

Comment: Hi Ruben,
thank you for your answer. This seems like solid a solution to me. I've managed to configure click for my python script. It works awesome while executing it from the command line like that:
`python3 ~/Desktop/Thesis/FeedMe/feed/priv/python/calculate_diet_4.py <arg1> <arg2> ...`

However I have a problem while executing it via `System.cmd/2` - it returns me :enoent.

```System.cmd("python3 ~/Desktop/Thesis/FeedMe/feed/priv/python/calculate_diet_4.py", ["#{products_json}", "#{meal_statistics_json}", "--lower_boundary=0.25",  "--upper_boundary=3.5", "--enhance=10"])```

Comment: Might be the `~` home prefix is not supported. Try `/usr/<yourname>/Desktop/Thesis/FeedMe/feed/priv/python/calculate_diet_4.py` instead

Comment: Still same results, the path to the file without `~` prefix is:
`/Users/mac/Desktop/Thesis/FeedMe/feed/priv/python/calculate_diet_4.py` - and again works fine while executing from the command line, but the `System.cmd/2` responds with `:enoent`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181022/5015356) says you might need to put the filename with the other arguments. `System.cmd("python3", ["/Users/mac/Desktop/Thesis/FeedMe/feed/priv/python/calculate_diet_4.py", "#{products_json}", "#{meal_statistics_json}", "--lower_boundary=0.25",  "--upper_boundary=3.5", "--enhance=10"])`

Comment: Calling it via: `"cmd command" |> String.to_charlist() |> :os.cmd()` solved it! Thank you for help!

Putting filename with the other arguments also works :)

Comment: Great! Happy to help!